# Training a Perceptron model

Tags: c++, neural-network, perceptron

Following [The Coding Train awesome video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntKn5TPHHAk) I'm using a Perceptron model to train a Neural Network on an XOR gates.

I have 2 inputs and 1 output.

Most of my code is very similar to the video, beside I'm using a different data set of XOR gates.

I'm running into problem after training the model, it doesn't guess the correct answer even after 10 of thousands of training datas and I'm not sure why.

Here is my full code:

Perceptron.h

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf, puts, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

class Perceptron {
private:
    vector<float> weights;
    float lr = 0.15;
public:
    Perceptron() {
        // initialize the weights randomly 
        srand(time(NULL));
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            int x = -1 + rand() % (3);
            while (x == 0)
                x = -1 + rand() % (3);
            weights.push_back(x);
        }
    }
    int sign(float n) // activation function
    {
        if (n >= 0)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    int guess(vector<float> inputs)
    {
        float sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < weights.size(); i++)
        {
            sum += inputs[i] * weights[i];
        }

        int output = sign(sum);
        return output;
    }
    void train(vector<float> inputs, int target)
    {
        int guess1 = guess(inputs);
        int error = target - guess1;
        for (int i = 0; i < weights.size(); i++) {
            weights[i] += error * inputs[i] * lr;
        }
    }
};
```

Training.h

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf, puts, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */
#include <iostream>  
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

class XOR {
private:
    float x1;
    float x2;
    float label;

public:
    XOR() {

        x1 = rand() % (2);
        x2 = rand() % (2);

        if (x1 == 0 && x2 == 0)
            label = 0;
        else if (x1 == 0 && x2 == 1)
            label = 1;
        else if (x1 == 1 && x2 == 0)
            label = 1;
        else
            label = 0;
    }

    float getX1(){ return x1; };
    float getX2() { return x2; };
    float getLabel() { return label; };

    vector<float> getInputs() {
        return vector<float> {x1, x2};
    }
    float getTarget() {
        return label;
    }
    
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Perceptron.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Training.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    Perceptron brain;
    vector<XOR> trainingData(100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        brain.train(trainingData[i].getInputs(), trainingData[i].getTarget());
    }
    
    vector<float> inputs = { 0,0 };
    vector<float> inputs2 = { 0,1 };
    vector<float> inputs3 = { 1,0 };
    vector<float> inputs4 = { 1,1 };

    int guess1 = 0;

    guess1 = brain.guess(inputs);
    cout  << "guess: " << guess1 << endl;

    guess1 = brain.guess(inputs2);
    cout << "guess: " << guess1 << endl;

    guess1 = brain.guess(inputs3);
    cout << "guess: " << guess1 << endl;

    guess1 = brain.guess(inputs4);
    cout << "guess: " << guess1 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

you can run this code on your machine and test it for yourself, if you notice when you run it multiple times you get different output which is even more odd.

Comment: But isn't perceptron known to be **not enough** to learn XOR operation?

Comment: You need another model to learn it

Comment: `// initialize the weights randomly` what if you initialize the weights the same every time? Different initial weights will probably give you different output right?

Comment: Try to add `float bias;` to your perceptron, initialize it randomly, in `guess` you add it to sum, and in `train` add it considering `error * lr`

Comment: No, the weights are changing based on the training, so it should always get to the same result no matter the weights being different. @mattlangford

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to converge to exactly the same weights every time. Are you able to confirm that they are?

Comment: I think I'm getting the different outputs because each time I generate a slightly different dataset. @mattlangford

Comment: I didn't quite understand how that should look in code, where do I add the bias in the train() function? when multiplying? @AlexeyLarionov

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use an additional bias weight with the value of 1, incase the inputs are 0,0.

Other then that the model I'm using to learn XOR operation is too basic because it doesn't work with more than 2 scenarios.